# Moving Gif in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, gif

How can I add a moving Gif in pygame for a simple loop? I tried normal image importing but the .gif was invisible. Any ideas on how to do this? I want to do it for a new game I'm making with the main characters legs moving and fire to move. I haven't tried sprites in pygame because image importing is easy enough and it has worked thus far for static images with maybe a change to face different directions

I've tried simply this:

```
img = pygame.image.load("img.gif")
```

I blit'd it onto the screen. Invisible. I tried it with a .PNG and it was visible.

Comment: If your question was not a duplicated (which it is) it would be better received if you posted the code that you tried, FWIW.

Comment: You can't do that. `pygame` does not allow.

Comment: @AHuman you *can* work around it.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, he's posted all the code he's tried, you can't ask for much more code than that, it wouldn't help.

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick True, but it takes a LOT of work.

Comment: @AHuman, actually not a lot, but a lot more than one would think :)

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick that code was not posted in response to my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** You cannot do that using `pygame.image.load`

**Long answer:** Yes, there *is* a work around.

1. Extract each of the images from the gif (if on a Mac use [this](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/preview-extracting-frames-from-animated-gifs)).
2. Add all the image names to a list
3. Using a `for` loop, load them all and put it in a dictionary                                                                   <sub>you can use another list for this instead, your choice.</sub>

---

```
img_names = [*my image names*]
all_imgs = {}
for img in img_names:
    all_imgs[img] = pygame.image.load(img)
```

---

4. Then looping through `img_names`, you can `blit` each image to the screen

---

```
for img in img_names:
    screen.blit(all_imgs[img], (desiredx, desiredy))
```

Comment: I did this and it only loaded one image... Same code exactly but didnt work